# Output HTML with if/then Javascript?

Tags: javascript

The following javascript works but I want to replace the words "YOUTUBE" with a font awesome icon. The variable "type" will either be YOUTUBE or VIMEO or SOUNDCLOUD, so I am trying to incorporate a JS if/then statement in the middle of the spaghetti...

This is the code:

```
playlistHtml  += "<li>"+val.sources[0].type+" Song Name Here</li>"
```

This is the output:

YOUTUBE Song Name Here

```
playlistHtml  += "<li><div id='logo'></div>"+
   if (val.sources[0].type == "YOUTUBE") 
   {
      document.getElementById('logo').innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-youtube-play' aria-hidden='true'></i> Song Name Here</li>";});
```

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: So what is your expected output?

Comment: Your question title does not match your question/code. Where is the PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function which returns the `font awesome` class. 
And call like this.

```
document.getElementById('logo').innerHTML = "<i class='fa "+getIcon(val.sources[0].type)+"' aria-hidden='true'></i> Song Name Here</li>";
```

Function :

```
function getIcon(source){
    switch(source.toUpperCase()){
        case "YOUTUBE" : return "fa-youtube-play"
        case "VIMEO" : return "fa-vimeo"
        case "SOUNDCLOUD" : return "fa-soundcloud"
        default : return "fa-music"
    }
}
```

Comment: No need for `break` if you `return`.

Comment: Yeah! I am kinda habituated to use that with switch. :P Anyway edited !

Answer (score 2):

This is untested, I've just restructured your code a little.

```
playlistHtml  += "<li><div id='logo'>";
if (val.sources[0].type == "YOUTUBE") {
  playlistHtml += "<i class='fa fa-youtube-play' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
}
if (val.sources[0].type == "VIMEO") {
  playlistHtml += "<i class='fa fa-vimeo-play' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
}
if (val.sources[0].type == "SOUNDCLOUD") {
  playlistHtml += "<i class='fa fa-soundcloud-play' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
}
playlistHtml += "</div>Song Name Here</li>";
```